# How to realize an automatic-size toolbar?

Tags: html, css

I have a toolbar, which includes many buttons(show in one line). Now I have a problem that when the window size is too small, the buttons will be covered. So I want the toolbar can adjust its width and height automatically, the covered buttons can go to next line to display. How can I realize this by CSS? It's OK if it needs Javascripts.
The style is quite same as Google Spreadsheet's Show More button.
[Toolbar Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYX0l.png)

Comment: Please, add your code so far

Answer (score 0):

i think,you mean you want to make it responsive according to the page size?
then you can use a meta tag in your html page

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that applying a percentage-based width to your toolbar may solve your problem:

```
.toolbar {
   width:100%;
   display:block;
}
```